# Sobolev embedding for the $L^q$ norm.

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, regularity-theory-of-pdes, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Suppose $f \in H^1(\mathbb R^2)$, where $H^1$ is the Sobolev space, then how to use this information to bound $\Vert f \Vert_{L^q}$, where $q>2$? It seems like Sobolev embedding, but it's not.

Comment: @Zixiao_Liu "Also $W^{1,2}$ norm will provides a Hardy Inequality, which can bound weighted  norm with singular weights." Are you able to provide some reference for this statement? I'm not saying it's wrong, just don't know why.

Comment: On Wikipedia, you can easily find:
Hardy Inequality origins from 1-dimension integral by parts. 
Due to Szego Inequality and Riesz Rearrangement inequality, we only need to concern for radial symmetric functions that blows up at the origin. So there would be a suitable weight such that u is weighted integrable on entire $R^2$.
More detail I refer to  the book"Weighted inequalities of Hardy Type". Maybe I'm wrong about this idea, sorry I didn't recheck it again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is immediate from the [Gagliardo-Nirenberg inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gagliardo%E2%80%93Nirenberg_interpolation_inequality), or from the [Sobolev inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality) with fractional exponents, which says in particular that
$$
\|f\|_{L^q} \leq C\|f\|_{H^s} \leq C'\|f\|_{H^1} , \qquad f\in C^1_0(\mathbb{R}^2),
$$
for $2\leq q<\infty$ and $s=1-\frac2q$.

Comment: but the question seems to be about $H^1$ i.e. $s=1$, or $q=\infty$

Comment: @CalvinKhor: $H^1$ is trivially embedded into $H^s$ with $s<1$. The question only asked about $q>2$, which I read as $2<q<\infty$.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're getting at now, thanks. I expected "worse" results than $H^1\subset BMO$ from using less regularity and BMO functions are only locally in $L^q$...

Comment: @timur  Does $C'$ depend on q?

Comment: Yes it will blow up in the limit $q\to\infty$, because $H^1$ is not embedded into $L^\infty$.

Comment: @timur More explicitly, $C'=Cq$, right?

Comment: Could you please explain how you get $C\|f\|_{H^s} \leq C'\|f\|_{H^1}$ ?

Comment: @StratosFair because s is less than 1