# Sobolev embedding of $H^1(\mathbb R^2)$ into $L^q(\mathbb R^2) $ : explicit dependence on $q$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Let $u\in H^1(\mathbb R^2)$, where $H^1(\mathbb R^2)\equiv W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^2)$ is the usual  Sobolev space with standard norm and inner product. I want to show that for any $1\le q <\infty$ (actually I believe it should be $2<q<\infty$), we have the inequality
$$\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^2)}\le C\sqrt{q} \|u\|_{H^1(\mathbb R^2)} \tag1$$

For some constant $C>0$ which does not depend on $u$.

By [Sobolev embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobolev_inequality#Sobolev_embedding_theorem), we know that for $s$ satisfying $1/q = 1/2 - s/2 $, we have the continuous embedding $W^{s,2}(\mathbb R^2)=H^s(\mathbb R^2)  \hookrightarrow L^q(\mathbb R^2)$, hence there exists $C_1>0$ such that

$$\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^2)}\le C_1 \|u\|_{H^{s}(\mathbb R^2)} \tag{1a} $$

Next, we need to find a constant $C_2>0$ such that
$$\|u\|_{H^{s}(\mathbb R^2)}\le C_2 \|u\|_{H^1(\mathbb R^2)} \tag{1b} $$

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3123405/857384) claims that $(1\text{b})$ is also a consequence of Sobolev embedding. By recursively applying the usual Sobolev inequality to $D^{s-1}u,D^{s-2}u,\ldots$ and so on, we can indeed show that the embedding $W^{s,2}(\mathbb R^2)\hookrightarrow W^{1,2_s^{*}}(\mathbb R^2)$ (where $2_s^{*}$ is the $(s-1)$th Sobolev conjugate of $2$) is continuous. However $W^{1,2_s^{*}}(\mathbb R^2)\ne W^{1,2}(\mathbb R^2)$, so I still fail to see why such a $C_2$ exists.

Regardless, assuming that $(1\text{b})$ holds, it can then be combined with $(1\text{a})$ and the fact that $1\le\sqrt q $ to conclude that
$$\|u\|_{L^q(\mathbb R^2)}\le C'\sqrt{q} \|u\|_{H^1(\mathbb R^2)} \tag{1'}$$
where $C'\equiv  C_1 C_2$, which is "technically" identity $(1)$.

However this is not satisfactory at all since the dependence of $C'$ on $q$ is not made explicit, and I think the point is rather to show that
$$C' \equiv C'(q) = C\sqrt q \tag2$$

Now I am a bit stuck in trying to prove $(2)$, I have tried explictly writing down the $L^q$-norm of $u$, playing with spherical coordinates and Young's inequality, but I can't seem to get the desired conclusion. I suspect the proof follows from the way inequality $(1\text{b})$ is obtained, but I am clueless so far.

Hence I ask for your help : **Why does the embedding $\mathbf{(1b)}$ hold ?** **And how to show $\mathbf{(2)} $ ?**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There must be a typo. (1b) is false for $p > 2$. It is not stated this way in the question you link to.

Comment: @cs89 thank you, I had indeed messed up the notations. Should be fixed now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cs89 answers your first question well, but the paper attached there seems to indicate that $C(q)^2\sim8\pi\mathrm{e}q$, which fits your desired result (2) well. This answer tries to verify and generalize the inequality (1) in a relatively elementary way.

I saw this inequality first in a note written by Steve Shkoller (see Theorem 2.30 in [Notes on $L^p$ and Sobolev Spaces](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Ehunter/m218a_09/Lp_and_Sobolev_notes.pdf)), and later a generalization to the $n$-dimensional case in the well-known textbook, *A First Course on Sobolev Spaces*, written by Giovanni Leoni (see Theorem 12.33 in the second edition). Both proofs in the above two references seem sort of technical at first sight. Nevertheless, a slight modification of the argument used by Lawrence Evans in his famous textbook *Partial Differential Equations* to prove Morrey's inequality can show that there exists a constant $C$ depending only on $n$ such that
\begin{equation}
||u||_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)}\le Cq^{1-1/n}||u||_{W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \tag{*}
\end{equation}
for any $u\in W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and any $n\le q<\infty$.

First, we claim that there exists a constant $C$ depending on $n$ such that
\begin{equation}
|u(x)|\le C\int_{B(x,1)}\frac{|u(y)|+|Du(y)|}{|y-x|^{n-1}}dy \tag{**}
\end{equation}
for any $u\in C^1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and any $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. It is clear that
$$
|u(x)| = \frac{1}{\alpha(n)}\int_{B(x,1)}|u(x)|dy \le \frac{1}{\alpha(n)}\int_{B(x,1)}|u(y)-u(x)|+|u(y)|dy ,
$$
and
$$
\int_{B(x,1)}|u(y)|dy \le \int_{B(x,1)}\frac{|u(y)|}{|y-x|^{n-1}}dy.
$$
Also recall that it is shown in Evans' book that
$$
\int_{B(x,1)}|u(y)-u(x)|dy \le C\int_{B(x,1)}\frac{|Du(y)|}{|y-x|^{n-1}}dy . $$
Indeed, let $w$ be a point of the unit sphere $\partial B(0,1)$ and let $0<s<1$. Then
$$
|u(x+sw)-u(x)|  \le \int_0^s|Du(x+tw)|dt .
$$
Hence,
$$
\int_{\partial B(0,1)}|u(x+sw)-u(x)|dS(w) \le \int_{\partial B(0,1)}\int_0^s|Du(x+tw)|dtdS(w) .
$$
Now
$$\int_{\partial B(0,1)}\int_0^s|Du(x+tw)|dtdS(w) = \int_{B(x,s)}\frac{|Du(y)|}{|y-x|^{n-1}}dy 
$$
and
$$
\int_{\partial B(0,1)}|u(x+sw)-u(x)|dS(w)=s^{-(n-1)}\int_{\partial B(x,s)}|u(y)-u(x)|dS(y)
$$
We obtain
$$
\int_{\partial B(x,s)}|u(y)-u(x)|dS(y) \le s^{n-1}\int_{B(x,1)}\frac{|Du(y)|}{|y-x|^{n-1}}dy ,
$$
and integrating with respect to $s$ from $0$ to $1$ yields
$$
\int_{B(x,s)}|u(y)-u(x)|dy \le \frac{1}{n}\int_{B(x,1)}\frac{|Du(y)|}{|y-x|^{n-1}}dy .
$$

From (**) and Young's inequality of convolutions, we get
\begin{align*}
||u||_{L^q(\mathbb{R}^n)} &\le C\left(\int_{B(0,1)}|x|^{-\frac{n(n-1)q}{(n-1)q+n}}dx\right)^{1-1/n+1/q}||u||_{W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)} \\
&\le C\left(\frac{(n-1)q+n}{n^2}\right)^{1-1/n+1/q}||u||_{W^{1,n}(\mathbb{R}^n)} .
\end{align*}
Notice that $q^{1/q}\to1$ as $q\to\infty$, from which (*) follows.

Comment: wow, this is super awesome, thanks a lot ! And welcome to MSE by the way ;)

Comment: Just as a small comment, for the Young's Inequality to hold, we need $q,n\geq 1$ and $1-\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{q}\leq 1$, which implies $q\geq n.$

Answer (score 2):

Let me answer both questions.

1. Your intermediate bound (1b) above holds with $C_1 = 1$ and is immediate using the Fourier-based definition of the considered norms. Indeed, for $s \in [0,1]$,
   $$ \| u \|_{H^s(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2
   = \int (1+|\xi|^2)^{s} |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2 \mathrm{d}\xi
   \leq \int (1+|\xi|^2)^{1} |\hat{u}(\xi)|^2\mathrm{d}\xi = \|u\|_{H^1(\mathbb{R}^2)}^2,
   $$
   sine $a^s \leq a$ for any real $a\geq1$ and $s \in [0,1]$.
2. **Your desired bound (1) does NOT hold with a constant $\sqrt{q}$.** This is linked with the topic of "best constants" in Sobolev inequalities. Here, you are looking for the best constant for the embedding of $H^1(\mathbb{R}^2) = W^{1,2}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ in $L^q(\mathbb{R}^2)$ for $2 \leq q < + \infty$. The correct asymptotic behavior of $C(q)$ with respect to $q$ as $q \to + \infty$ is
   $$
   C(q) \sim 8 \pi e q,
   $$
   so is linear in $q$ (not $\sqrt{q}$). From this asymptotic behavior, you can deduce that there exists $\bar{C} > 0$ (independent of $q$) such that your inequality holds with $\bar{C} q$ for every $q \in [2,\infty)$. This asymptotic behavior is for example stated as Theorem 1.7 in the following paper (of which you can find a copy [here](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Daniele-Cassani/publication/333506945_Bounds_for_best_constants_in_subcritical_Sobolev_embeddings/links/5cf0be66299bf1fb184bae3a/Bounds-for-best-constants-in-subcritical-Sobolev-embeddings.pdf)).

*Cassani, Daniele; Tarsi, Cristina; Zhang, Jianjun*, [**Bounds for best constants in subcritical Sobolev embeddings**](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.na.2019.05.012), Nonlinear Anal., Theory Methods Appl., Ser. A, Theory Methods 187, 438-449 (2019). [ZBL1423.35010](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1423.35010).

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was very helpful for me.